# Rails get records using date ranges

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application I have a table named JobTech and with in the table I have two columns `JobStartDate` and `JobFinishDate`. Now want to show the job with starting date today and also the jobs with finishing date today. I have tried a lot things but didn't get a solution.

Can someone tell how to do this?

My table structure is like:

```
class CreateJobTeches < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change

    create_table :job_teches do |t|
      t.integer :job_id
      t.integer :technician_id
      t.date :JobStartDate
      t.time :JobStartTime
      t.date :JobFinishDate
      t.time :JobFinishTime
      t.integer :DueBy
      t.integer :Jobscheduled

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried something like:

```
JobTech.where("JobStartDate >= ? and JobFinishDate <= ?", Date.yesterday, Date.today)
```

Comment: No need to show jobs finishing today and jobs starting today.

Comment: I think it is correct 'want to show the job with starting date today and also the jobs with finishing date today'

Comment: I have JobTech.where("JobStartDate = ? OR JobFinishDate <= ?",Date.today,Date.today) but this show Undefined Column jobstartdate error

Comment: Executive summary: say `t.date :job_start_date` and use `job_start_date >= ?` in the SQL or keep using mixed case column names and double quote them in the SQL (`where('"JobStartDate" >= ? ...')`).

Comment: It is showing the undefined column error ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JobTech.where("JobStartDate = ? or JobFinishDate = ?", Date.today, Date.today)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: What is the name of your column in DB?

Comment: Try `JobTech.where("JobStartDate = ? or JobFinishDate = ?", Date.today, Date.today)`

Comment: I have already tried it but showing the same result >>> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "jobstartdate" does not exist

Comment: This is PG issue, try renaming columns in DB to lowercase and it should work fine!

Comment: okay I will try. Is there any other solution for it ?

Comment: I tried JobTech.where(:JobStartDate =>  Date.today) it is working fine with same name ?